Bounding the coefficients of a polynomial written as the sum of powers of linear forms
Crosspost: Just a heads up, I've posted this question on math.stackexchange as well. I have made new attempts at solving it though, and figured I'd ask here since it's more of a research-level question.

Background:
Let $\mathfrak{F}(n,d)$ denote the space of forms (i.e., homogeneous polynomials) of degree $d$ with coefficients in $\mathbb{C}$ in $n$ variables.
It is well known, (for example, see Białynicki-Birula and Schinzel) that any $F(x_1,\dots,x_n) \in \mathfrak{F}(n,d)$ can be written as a superposition of $d$th powers of linear forms, i.e.,
$$\begin{align}
F(x_1,\dots,x_n) &= \sum_{\mu=1}^m L_\mu(x_1,\dots,x_n)^d\\
&= \sum_{\mu=1}^m \left( b_{\mu,1} x_1 + \dots b_{\mu,n} x_n \right)^d\\
&= \sum_{\mu=1}^m \left(\mathbf{b}_\mu \cdot \mathbf{x}\right)^d
\end{align}$$
where $m \le {n+d-2 \choose d-1}$ and $\mathbf{b}_\mu \in \mathbb{C}^n$.
Problem:
Suppose that we are guaranteed that $|F(\mathbf{x})| \le 1$ for all $\mathbf{x} \in \mathbb{D}^n$ where $\mathbb{D}$ is the closed unit complex disk. The goal is to obtain a bound on the one-norm of the vectors $\|\mathbf{b}_\nu \|_1$.
If you would like, you could even assume that the $F \in \mathbb{R}$ whenever $\mathbf{x} \in [-1,1]^n$.
Conjecture: $ \|\mathbf{b}_\nu\|_1 \le 2$ for all $1 \le \nu \le m$.

Attempt 1:
I've been running around in circles trying to obtain a bound on the vectors $\mathbf{b}_\nu$, or else find a counter-example, but to no avail.
Hölder's inequalities seem completely useless, as they give us upper-bounds on $|F|$ rather than lower bounds.
Fix $1 \le \nu \le m$.
The most fruitful direction I found as to define a vector $\mathbf{a} \in \mathbb{C}^n$ such that $b_{\nu,i} a_i = |b_{\nu}|$ (i.e., $a_i$ is equal to the complex conjugate of the phase of $b_{\nu,i}$). Then,
$$\begin{align}
F(\mathbf{a}) &= \left( \mathbf{b}_\nu \cdot \mathbf{a} \right)^d + \sum_{\mu \ne \nu} \left( \mathbf{b}_\mu \cdot \mathbf{a} \right)^d\\
&= \left( \sum_{i=1}^n |b_{\nu,1}|  \right)^d + \sum_{\mu \ne \nu} \left( \mathbf{b}_\mu \cdot \mathbf{a} \right)^d\\
\Rightarrow |F(\mathbf{a})| &= \left| \|\mathbf{b}_\nu\|_1^d + \sum_{\mu \ne \nu} \left( \mathbf{b}_\mu \cdot \mathbf{a} \right)^d \right| \le 1
\end{align}$$
but then I get stuck, as each $\left( \mathbf{b}_\mu \cdot \mathbf{a} \right)^d$ could possibly be negative.

Attempt 2:
To simplify things, let's consider a degree $d$ form in $2$ variables with real coefficients, i.e., $ F(x,y) \in \mathfrak{F}_\mathbb{R}(2,d)$. Then $\dim \mathfrak{F}_\mathbb{R}(2,d) = d+1$ since $\{ x^r y^{d-r}\}_{0 \le r \le d}$ span this space.
This post shows that for any set of real numbers $0 < a_1 < \dots < a_{d+1}$, the linear forms $L_i(x,y) := \left( x + a_i y \right)^d$ span $\mathfrak{F}_\mathbb{R}(2,d)$ as well. It follows that there exists $\mathbf{b} \in \mathbb{R}^{d+1}$ such that
$$\begin{align}
F(x,y) &= \sum_{i=1}^{d+1} b_i \left( x + a_i y \right)^d
\end{align}$$
This is great, because now we can control the size of the coefficients of $L_i$, but I still can't see how to bound the vector $\mathbf{b}$. Since this matrix
$$\begin{bmatrix}
1 & \binom{d}{1}a_1 & \binom{d}{2}a_1^2 & \cdots & \binom{d}{d}a_1^d \\
1 & \binom{d}{1}a_2 & \binom{d}{2}a_2^2 & \cdots & \binom{d}{d}a_2^d \\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots\\
1 & \binom{d}{1}a_s & \binom{d}{2}a_s^2 & \cdots & \binom{d}{d}a_s^d 
\end{bmatrix}$$
maps the $\{ x^r y^{d-r}\}_{0 \le r \le d}$ basis to the $\{ L_r(x,y) \}_{0 \le r \le d}$ basis, I'm thinking maybe the spectral norm of its inverse could be used to bound the possible $\mathbf{b}$? This also makes me think that perhaps the norm of $\mathbf{b}$ is dependent on the choice of $a_i$... so let's restrict $a_{d+1} \le 1$.

Examples:
Here are some examples of polynomials written as superpositions of powers of linear forms. In the case of single-variable polynomials, it is useful to consider the Chebyshev polynomials $T_d(x)$, as they automatically satisfy that $|F| \le 1$ condition. Note that not all of these are homogeneous, but I'm trying to use the homogeneous result to prove a more general result, as any degree $d$ polynomial $p(x_1,\dots,x_n)$ can be made homogeneous by defining $x_0^d p(x_1/x_0,\dots,x_n/x_0)$, applying the result, then setting $x_0 = 1$.
$$\begin{align}
xy &= \left(\frac{1}{2} x + \frac{1}{2} y \right)^2 + \left(\frac{i}{2} x - \frac{i}{2} y \right)^2\\
T_4(x) = 1 - 8 x^2 + 8 x^4 &= 4\left(x + i/\sqrt{6}\right)^4 + 4\left(x - i/\sqrt{6}\right)^4 + 7/9\\
T_5(x) = 5 x - 20 x^3 + 16 x^5 &= \frac{75}{4}x^5+\frac{1}{8} (x-2)^5-\frac{3}{2} (x-1)^5-\frac{3}{2} (x+1)^5+\frac{1}{8} (x+2)^5
\end{align}$$

Any counterexamples or suggestions on ways to move forward would be highly appreciated!
Also apologies in advance for how long this post is... there's no need to read the entire attempts/examples sections.

Such a representation may happen to be by much not unique, even with the smallest number of summands. Are you interested in the existence of a “small” representation, or in the proof that every minimal representation has small coefficients (this surely does not hold without the minimality assumption)?

@IlyaBogdanov that's a good question. I am not interested in the existence of a small representation (i.e., "the Waring problem for polynomials"). Just given such a representation, I'm interested in the size of the coefficients.
It's also not clear to me why the coefficients wouldn't be small without the minimality assumption? I do want to bound the number of terms by the $m$ given in the problem statement though..

@AlkaKadri given such a representation, I'm interested in the size of the coefficients In this case you are doomed: take a huge $b$ and perturb it a tiny bit to $b'$. Then $(b,x)^d-(b',x)^d$ can be made as small as you wish on any compact you want...

In your representation, you may easily have the summands $(\mathbf b\cdot\mathbf x)^d+(\varepsilon\mathbf b\cdot \mathbf x)^d$, where $\varepsilon^d=-1$; they make a zero impact, and the norm of $\mathbf b$ may be arbitrary. There are also different, not-so-easy-to-find, similar cases.

Ahhh I see.. thank you for pointing out these cases! I suppose I should focus then on whether a construction exists such that the $\mathbf{b}_\nu$ are bounded by some constant (and the constant doesn't depend on the function $F$ so long as $|F| \le 1$)

In other words, it makes much more sense to focus on "the existence of a small representation", as you originally pointed out @IlyaBogdanov (I originally understood "small" to mean small in the number of terms, but by small we mean $\mathbf{b}_\nu$ is bounded). Should I update the question to reflect this? I'm kind of new to MO so I'm not sure of the etiquette here.

You can update your post if it happens that the original one makes no sense, and if you are interested in the updated version.

But, again, take into account that you may split one summand into a sum of two with smaller norms, or do something else. So you really need to put some minimality condition in this case as well

I see. So the basis vectors I gave in Attempt 2 are all linearly independent. If I take the linear combination of that basis that's equal to $F$ with $|F| \le 1$, and ask for the existence of a "small" $\mathbf{b}$, do you still see an issue?
